# Open an application from Oracle?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

This seems like something so simple but it may not even be possible. I'm very new to SQL but have developed a report that is exporting to an excel spreadsheet. Is there coding that can actually open the excel spreadsheet? I don't mean like link to it or import it. I mean literally open it instead of me fumbling through folders. The coding is in Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: What language are you coding this in ?

Comment: I'm doing this in SQL Developer. I've done extensive VBA coding before directly in Excel but I'm not sure this is possible within SQL Developer.

Comment: Huh, that's probably not a simple task (or, to be honest, I don't know how to do that). SQL itself can't do it, so you'd need PL/SQL. PL/SQL runs in the database, on a database server (which is, probably, not your PC). Therefore, I'd still say that it is simpler to fumble through folders. Google for "run operating system commands from sql", maybe you'll find something useful.

Comment: in sqldev, you made a report under Views -> Reports Then under User Defined Reports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a script in [SQLcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/downloads/index.html) that dumps the query results to a csv then opens it.

the same script will work in the SQL Developer worksheet.

The script

- turns off headers and feedback.
- sets the format of the results to CSV
- Spools the results to "users.csv"
- Stops spooling
- Issues "host open users.csv" which tells the O/S to open the file which should be excel unless the os has csv associated to another application

  ```
  sql klrice/klrice

  SQLcl: Release 18.1 Production on Wed Feb 07 17:28:32 2018

  Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

  Last Successful login time: Wed Feb 07 2018 17:28:56 -05:00

  Connected to:
  Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production


  SQL> set hea off
  SQL> set feed off
  SQL> set sqlformat csv
  SQL> spool users.csv
  SQL> select * from user_objects;
  ...rows.....
  SQL> spool off
  SQL> host open users.csv
  ```

Comment: After further research it looks like that's exactly what I need. Doesn't seem to work for me though. It get an error when I run it. on Host open myfile.csv. It says that it basically doesn't understand what "host" is. I marked it has correct because the further I've delved into this the more I'm seeing that solution.

Comment: sorry "open" is on osx. For windows it's "start", so change the above to "host start users.csv"

Comment: Man it's so close now! Different error now. It tries to open the file now but says it can't find the file.

Comment: probably have to path out the file then... spool /tmp/users.csv then start /tmp/users.csv